# Create AbstractBaseUser

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Try to create AbstractBaseUser and custom auth.

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    account_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birthday_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=320)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField()
    expired_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=False)
    account_type = models.TextField()  # This field type is a guess.

    objects = AccountManager

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'registration_date', 'account_type']

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'account'
```

AccountManager

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, birthday_date, sex, country, city, email,
                    mobile_number, registration_date, expired_date, account_type, password):

        fields = [first_name, last_name, birthday_date, sex, country, email,
                  mobile_number, registration_date, expired_date, account_type, password]

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            birthday_date=birthday_date,
            sex=sex,
            country=country,
            city=city,
            mobile_number=mobile_number,
            registration_date=registration_date,
            expired_date=expired_date,
            account_type=account_type,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

setting.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'models',
        ...]
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'models.Account'

    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('models.backend.EmailOrPhoneBackend',)
```

backend.py

```
class EmailOrPhoneBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            # Try to fetch the user by searching the username or email field
            user = Account.objects.get(Q(mobile_number=username) | Q(email=username))
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except Account.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
            Account().set_password(password)
```

I try to creatae new user by parsing post data and saving it to db:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    postDict = dict(request.POST)

    account = Account();

    for element in postDict:
        jsonPostDict = json.loads(element)

        for value in jsonPostDict:

            print('key is : ' + value)
            print('value is : ' + jsonPostDict[value])

            if value == 'firstName':
                account.first_name = jsonPostDict[value]
                print('set first name')
            if value == 'lastName':
                account.last_name = jsonPostDict[value]
                print('set last name')
            if value == 'email':
                account.email = jsonPostDict[value]
                print('set email')
            if value == 'password':
                account.set_password(jsonPostDict[value])
                print('set password')

    account.account_type = 'free'
    account.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin", request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Log:

```
key is : firstName
value is : a
set first name
key is : email
value is : artem@gmail.com
set email
key is : password
value is : qwdsfgh23e
set password
key is : lastName
value is : a
set last name
Internal Server Error: /signup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: ERROR:  row "password" in table "account" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "account" ("password", "last_login", "first_name...
                               ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/finstatement/project/account_management/views.py", line 44, in post
    account.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1045, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1054, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ОШИБКА:  row "password" in table "account" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "account" ("password", "last_login", "first_name...
                               ^

[15/Oct/2016 08:40:22] "POST /signup HTTP/1.1" 500 147276
```

I should add password row to my database or, I make some mistakes in customization of auth or backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at you `Account` model. There is no `password` field. You should add this field and than you can save data there.